# Can't access related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm

I am really under pressure and totally new to Rails. Project due in two days.

I have done a search on Rails console for a user inputted in my database `user = user.find(1)` and it returns.

the user has_many recipes 
recipes belongs to user  ....defined in user and recipe models respectively.

I am getting the error.

> undefined method "recipe" for user?

This is how I created my User

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     create_table :users do |t|
     t.integer "position"
     t.boolean "visible", :default => false
     t.string "restaurant_name", :limit => 25
     t.string "username", :limit => 25
     t.string "password", :limit => 50
     t.string "hashed_email", :default => "", :null => false
     t.string "address1", :limit => 80
     t.string "address2", :limit => 80
     t.string "address3", :limit => 80
     t.string "county", :limit => 40
     t.string "telephone", :limit => 40
     t.text "web address", :limit => 60
     t.string "photo_path", :limit => 100
     t.text "description", :limit => 2000
     t.text "salt", :string, :limit => 50
      t.timestamps
   end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Recipe

```
    class CreateRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :recipes do |t|
      t.integer "user_id"
      t.string "recipe_name", :limit => 100
      t.integer "greedy_type", :default => 0
      t.string "photo_path", :limit => 40
      t.text "description", :limit => 400
      t.text "recipe", :limit => 4000
      t.integer "ingredient1", :limit => 40
      t.integer "ingredient2", :limit => 40
      t.integer "ingredient3", :limit => 40
      t.integer "ingredient4", :limit => 40
      t.string "permalink"
      t.integer "position"
      t.boolean "visible", :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("recipes", "user_id")
    add_index("recipes", "permalink")
   end

  def self.down
    drop_table :recipes
  end
 end
```

users.rb

```
    class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :recipes
    end
```

recipe.rb

```
   class Recipes < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :users
        has_many :restaurants
    end
```

ERROR

```
irb(main):005:0> users.recipe
NoMethodError: undefined method `recipe' for #<Users:0x599ebc0>
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:
392:in `method_missing'
       from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.r
b:46:in `method_missing'
```

Comment: Show your `User` and `Recipe` classes, please.

Comment: Why are you storing recipe_id in the users model? With a has_many relationship, you should instead put the user_id in the recpies model. By the way are you storing the password in clear text?

Answer (score 7):

If `User` has_many `recipes`, why you add field `recipe_id` for `user`? You should add `user_id` field to the `Recipe` class table. After creating `recipe` just store `user_id` and that is all you need. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. I rebuilt the whoel application.

Comment: *users.recipe* should be user.recipes(singular)

Answer (score 2):

as user has many recipes,

you have to write something like to get first users recipe..

```
recipe = user.recipes.first
```

and store user_id in recipe table.